# User trying to get us to do his work

Tags: support

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems like all his questions correspond to one script.
So I think he is using Stack Overflow to do his work.
Thought this is bad behaviour.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1129286/jackson?tab=summary

Comment: A quick glance at the user's questions indeed shows that they might all pertain to the same script, but they are still quite reasonable IMHO. They're not always very understandable but they do include code, often show some research effort, and the user does accept answers. I've seen far worse. Maybe flagging specific questions would be a better approach than reporting this user on meta?

Comment: Disagree with the comment above. I thought the questions look very poor and most are either NARQ or too localized IMO.

Comment: @Martin, I personally don't find [delete a clone from drop box in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8738713/464709), [Resize option of the jQuery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8819354/464709), or [Div resize in jQuery after dropped](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8815263/464709) to be either NARQ or too localized. Other questions may be, but those can be flagged individually.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: "I want to do x, this is my code, it does not work", literally, are not good questions...and every single one I checked so far fall into that category.

Comment: @Bobby, we're in agreement here, but none of the questions I linked to actually match that pattern. I'm not saying these questions are perfect or that all the questions from this user should be kept unflagged. However, reporting the user as always asking bad questions does not look actually fair or justified to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many people come to Stack Overflow with their job tasks for help - nothing new here.

If you think he's not putting enough effort to trying to do this by himself feel free to downvote the relevant questions.. after enough questions are downvoted the [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi) hammer will strike and he won't be able to post any more questions.

Just one thing to remember: don't downvote all his questions at once as the system will see this as "serial downvote" and cancel it.

Comment: What is *question ban hammer*?

Comment: @Piotr http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/ (edited my answer with the link as well)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: If a user posts too many bad questions and gets lots of downvotes, they will no longer be allowed to post new questions.